# Conditional expectation with a Poisson Process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

There is a Poisson process described by the constant intensity $\lambda >0$.

Given that at time $T$ we have encountered the tenth arrival, find the conditional expectation $E[W_1 W_2 \dots W_9\mid W_{10}=T]$.

---

I know that $$\frac{W_r}{t}|W_n = T$$ is described by the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha = r, \beta=n-r$ and I therefore know how to calculate each individual expectation. But I'm not sure how to deal with this concerning the product of the expectations because I don't quite understand how the independence of the events.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This paper addresses the product of dependent beta random variables, although I don't know how useful it would be: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965908000955

Comment: Conditionally on $W_{10}=T$, the random set $\{W_1,\ldots,W_9\}$ is distributed like $\{TU_1,\ldots,TU_9\}$ for some i.i.d. $(U_n)$ uniform on $(0,1)$, hence $E(W_1\cdots W_9\mid W_{10}=T)=T^9E(U)^9=\left(\frac12\right)^9T^9$.

Answer (score 0):

You have that the set $\{W_{1},\ldots W_{n}\}$  has the same distribution that a vector of a independent random variable $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$ with a uniform distribution  in the interval $[0,t]$.

So , conditioning on $W_{10}=T$ the set $\{W_{1},\ldots W_{n}\}$  is distributed like: $TY_{1}, \ldots, TY_{n}$ iid Uniform on $(0,1)$, then $E(TY_{n})=\dfrac{T}{2}$.

Therefore,

$$ E(W_{1},\ldots, W_{9}|W_{10}=T)=E(TY_{1}, \ldots, TY_{9})=(\dfrac{T}{2})^{9}$$.

I hope, that like my answer.